# Spring Boot Throwing NotificationBroadcasterSupport::sendNotification NullPointerException for unsecured endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot-based backend (heavily modified from JHipster). I'm seeing the following error whenever any requests are made to unsecured paths. Looking for ideas on what might be causing it and how to alleviate the error. Thanks!

I'm pretty much using jhipster SecurityConfigurator with some slight modifications. See code below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport::class)
class SecurityConfiguration(private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService,
                            private val authenticationManagerBuilder: AuthenticationManagerBuilder,
                            private val tokenProvider: TokenProvider,
                            private val jHipsterProperties: JHipsterProperties,
                            private val corsFilter: CorsFilter,
                            private val problemSupport: SecurityProblemSupport) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

  private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration::class.java)

  @PostConstruct
  fun init() {
    try {
      authenticationManagerBuilder
          .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
          .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      throw BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e)
    }

  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  @Throws(Exception::class)
  override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean()
  }

  @Bean
  fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
    return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
  }

  @Bean
  fun grantedAuthorityDefaults(): GrantedAuthorityDefaults {
    return GrantedAuthorityDefaults("") // Remove the ROLE_ prefix
  }


  @Throws(Exception::class)
  override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
        .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
        .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
        .antMatchers("/content/**")
        .antMatchers("/test/**")
  }

  @Throws(Exception::class)
  override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/counties").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/websocket/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/webhooks/stripe").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter())
  }

  private fun securityConfigurerAdapter(): JWTConfigurer {
    return JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider)
  }
}
```

Whenever my angular site hits the `/api/authenticate` endpoint I get the following error:

```
2019-06-07 17:46:37.014 DEBUG 22072 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] javax.management                         : NotificationBroadcasterSupport::sendNotification

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.lambda$registerMetricsEventually$aa4da135$1(TomcatMetrics.java:260)
    at java.management/javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:238)
    at java.management/javax.management.MBeanServerDelegate.sendNotification(MBeanServerDelegate.java:211)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.sendNotification(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1473)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1867)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:955)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:890)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:320)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:639)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.register(AbstractProtocol.java:1061)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:825)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Note: It actually doesn't effect the functionality of the application but I'd rather not have my application throwing errors every time someone tries to hit the login page...

Comment: Found any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no